# How to programmatically control VLC seek in milliseconds?

Tags: c#, vlc

I'm writing an app in C# that's controlling two VLC instances via VLC's remote control interface.  I need to be able to control the position in the stream of each instance as much as possible.  The RC seek command only gives control in seconds so any fraction of a second is impossible.

Does anyone have a recommendation that will allow me to control seek to milliseconds in C#?  I've looked at C# wrappers but none are maintained for the current version of VLC.  I'd like to continue to use the RC interface for simplicity if possible.